# I’m looking for open data on the recent mysterious dog illness

Tags: data-request

I’ve seen maps of which states have seen the mysterious dog illness, like the one in this article (https://www.cbsnews.com/news/dogs-respiratory-illness-map-acirdc/).

What I would like to get hold of open data to produce a heat map to recognize which states have more cases, or even better which counties in those states are more at risk.

Thank you!

Comment: Looks like WA data is available by county at https://wastatedeptag.blogspot.com/